# Best way to *instantly* tell which process is slowing down your system?

Tags: windows, performance, process-monitoring, system-monitoring

I run Procmon, ProcExp, Process Hacker, and the resource monitors of Windows 7, and while some can give me a clue about CPU and IO use, I feel like there's a more integrated solution out there that would tell me better.

Any ideas? Or should I just keep watching the FileIO/Duration and Private Bytes on my existing tools?

Comment: what does "more integrated" mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is akin to someone punching you in the stomach and then asking you if you are going to be coughing up blood tomorrow while you are doubled over.

The amount of CPU resources necessary to figure out which process is slowing it down will cause further slowdown.  Until the CPU has cycles to spare, it is just going to cause further slowdown.  On top of that, you have to ask yourself, "Do you really want a tool that chews up that many CPU cycles running all the time?"

Even if the OS could tell you at that moment, it isn't the solution you are looking for.  Nor are the tools above what you want to use.  Computers don't just go haywire.  Science teaches us that everything id caused.

Performance Monitor(perfmon) should be the tool of your choice.  Use it to log Disk Usage, CPU Time, and Memory usage and a list of processes running.  When they spike, you can have Perfmon write events to the Event Logs.  Armed with these numbers, you can better determine what processes at what times are misbehaving.

The above tools you list just don't offer the same utility.

Comment: I don't believe there are no clever ways to do it. E. g. it might be inactive most of the time and only triggered by certain amount of resource drain.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I think Hardware Interrupts is a good metric to see. These slow your computer down in ways beyond just CPU %.